# .NET read XML and select elements based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm working on an ASP.Net MVC application.
In my application, I have an xml file where I save information to be available for the next run of the app.

Here is a sample of the XML:

```
<data>
  <event>
    <id><![CDATA[38079482]]></id>
    <start_date><![CDATA[2014-10-21 09:45]]></start_date>
    <end_date><![CDATA[2014-10-21 11:00]]></end_date>
    <text><![CDATA[38079482]]></text>
    <engineer_id><![CDATA[20602]]></engineer_id>
    <color><![CDATA[#00CCCC]]></color>
    <status><![CDATA[Dispatched]]></status>
    <customer><![CDATA[Reed Hayes]]></customer>
    <number><![CDATA[689-761-834    ]]></number>
    <category><![CDATA[N/A]]></category>
  </event>
  <event>
    <id><![CDATA[38129667]]></id>
    <start_date><![CDATA[2014-10-20 11:20]]></start_date>
    <end_date><![CDATA[2014-10-20 13:00]]></end_date>
    <text><![CDATA[38129667]]></text>
    <engineer_id><![CDATA[20525]]></engineer_id>
    <color><![CDATA[Red]]></color>
    <status><![CDATA[Cancelled]]></status>
    <customer><![CDATA[Gervase Griffin]]></customer>
    <number><![CDATA[400-401-401    ]]></number>
   <category><![CDATA[N/A]]></category>
  </event>
</data>
```

**In my controller, I would like to parse this file and only send "event" elements to my view which have "start_date" for today's current date.**

Controller method looks like this so far:

```
public void gatherXML()
{
    string path = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Tasks.xml");
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(path);
    doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;

    ViewBag.xml = doc.InnerXml;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I would like to parse my XML file to only retrieve elements whose start_date is today's current date.

Comment: You need LINQ to XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **LINQ to XML** to query the XML structure and get only the elements you need.

Here is an example to find the elements with a specific date:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

var res = new XDocument
    (new XElement("data", 
        (from i in doc.Root.Elements()
        where i.Element(XName.Get("start_date")).Value == "2014-10-21 09:45"
        select i)));

var xml = res.ToString(); // Reduced XML containing only the matching element
```

You could also use **XPath** and the older XmlDocument API to query the document:

```
var xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
XmlNode root = xdoc.DocumentElement;

// Select the nodes that match the date condition
XmlNodeList node = root.SelectNodes(
    "descendant::event[start_date='2014-10-21 09:45']");
```

Comment: thanks, the first solution works flawlessly!
I just need to organize some of my code before sending it off to the view now!